# CSS selector: how to style items [1-2][5-6][9-10] etc by pair

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of items, I want style them by group of two, and alternate style between groups. So items [1-2][5-6][9-10] could be `{ background-color: #C0C0C0 ;}` while [3-4][7-8][11-12]... could be `{ background-color: #FFF ;}`.

For a result such:

1. grey
2. grey
3. **black**
4. **black**
5. grey
6. grey
7. **black**
8. **black**
9. grey
10. grey
11. **black**
12. **black**
13. ...

Which CSS nth-child formula should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcjFk/2/)

---

Use    `:nth-child(4n+3), :nth-child(4n+4)`

**CSS:**

```
li:nth-child(4n+4), li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color:red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>YES</li>
    <li>YES</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>YES</li>
    <li>YES</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>No</li>
    <li>YES</li>
    <li>YES</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I suggest to switch to `:nth-child(4n+3), :nth-child(4n+4)`, this order make more sense, no ? I will accept your answer anyway as soon as SO allow me to do so.

Comment: +1 ! The `4n+3; 4n+4` answer is longer but more intuitive, perfect for begginers !

Comment: @Zenith, I downvoted initially because your first answer was wrong, but then I retracted my downvote when you corrected your answer. It's not about hating, but about providing accurate information.  ;)

Comment: Your selector was wrong, but I retracted my downvote and gave you an upvote when you edited your answer.  I don't see the problem.  You haven't lost any reputation points from my downvote and gained 10 from my upvote. I did edit the other answer to fix the selectors, but you had already fixed yours.  Honestly, I see no hypocrisy there at all.  If you've received another downvote, it's not from me.

Comment: Thanks for fixing mine too. Sadly, my customer refuses to use modern browsers, so I lack experience with them.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with 2 selectors

```
:nth-child(4n),:nth-child(4n-1){font-weight:bold}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mckm4/

Comment: +1 ! This `4n ; 4n-1` is the perfect answer for purists wishing to keep 2 characters out. The `4n+3; 4n+4` answer on the other side is more beginner-friendly (intuitive).

Answer (score 3):

```
li:nth-child(4n+1), li:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: #C0C0C0
}

li:nth-child(4n+3), li:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color: #FFF
}
```

This isn't particularly elegant, but it should serve.