# Select nth child select 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 etc

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a set of divs as follows,

```
<div class="selector">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

I want to provide background colour to divs 1,2,5,6,9,10 etc. How do I select the particular divs using nth selector? Is it possible?

PS: The number of divs may grow to n.

Comment: sorry, desc is correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector: how to style items \[1-2\]\[5-6\]\[9-10\] etc by pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328051/css-selector-how-to-style-items-1-25-69-10-etc-by-pair)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to select:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
+ +     + +     +  + ...
```

For that you can use:

```css
.selector>div:nth-child(4n+1), .selector>div:nth-child(4n+2){
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Thanks [@SureshPonnukalai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3607064/suresh-ponnukalai) for the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etmLjnau/).

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I just drank my coffee so I'm hyperactive :D

Comment: @VyasRao your welcome :) don't hate yourself, everyone makes simple mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

This equation will give you the sequence..

```
2n+[((-1)^(n+1))-3]/2
```

Comment: Appartently, it's referred to as an expression and not an equation. Pedantic I know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nth child concept for this.

```
div.selector:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Hello this wont meet the criteria

Answer (score -1):

I think by using nth-child is not good because of IE8 compatibility. Its better to use + sign `li + li` or by adding class each of div.

Comment: This is a comment and should not be used as answer